# mysql calculate using combination of sum and product formula

Tags: mysql, sql, cumulative-sum

I have a table in mysql with data looking like this example.

```
|ColA |ColB|
|:---- |:------:|
|A1   |B1  |
|A2   |B2  |
|A3   |B3  |
|A4   |B4  |
...
```

I want to calculate a columnn colc using the formula:
`C1 = A1*B1;`
`C2 = (C1+A2)*B2;`
`C3 = (C2+A3)*B3;`
`C4 = (C3+A4)*B4;`
...

ColA  ColB  ColC
`1     5    5`
`2     6    42`
`3     7    315`
`4     8    2552`

Comment: Use recursive CTE.

Comment: Your question assumes that there is an ordering in the table.  However, tables are *unordered*.  It is not clear what the ordering is.  Sample data and desired results would also make the question much clearer -- and more likely to be answered.  Hint:  Arithmetic on strings doesn't make sense.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you for your comment, sample data and output are provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive to_r as (select row_number() over (order by t.ColA) r, t.* from test_table t), 
     cte as (
        select t.r, t.ColA*t.ColB p from to_r t where t.r = 1
        union all
        select c.r+1, t1.ColB*(t1.ColA+c.p) from cte c join to_r t1 on t1.r = c.r+1
        
)
select p from cte;
```

See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b3667ddb282a6dfbbd71465f3cc54276).